# Mailing server configuration with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to do the following 
user send email to adcvfjkr@domain.com
redirect the adcvfjkr@domain.com  to a php file and then 
insert the  email into a database where the  usercode= adcvfjkr, adcvjkr is dynamic.
I'm not interrested in the PHP/mysql part , but am interrested in how to redirect anything sent to @dmonai.com to a php file ?

Comment: You need to use this: http://www.php.net/mailparse

Comment: This pretty much depends on the Mail Transfer Agent on your mailserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a good tutorial that uses postfix
http://jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/

To redirect *@domain.com you can try to put

`luser_relay = php@domain.com`

in your `main.cf`.

after that add the following line to your `/etc/aliases` file

`php: "| php -q /home/user/path/to/script.php"`

The alias file might be located on other places depending on your distro.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Do I need to put the Email adress in this line :
email+to+redirect: "| php -q /home/user/full/path/to/your/new/script.php"
I didn't see where the (anyting) is redirected !

Comment: I added all what you said and run the command newaliases and reloaded postfix , but still is not working.
does your answer cover all the emails Like *@domain.com ?

Comment: Can you help me here please ? @Markus

Comment: I assume you got it working since you marked it accepted. Please let me know if you didn't got it working and I'll improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through the hassle of having your own mail server for this, there are also a hand full of "SAAS-services" that take care of the mail part for you and give you json:

http://mandrill.com/
https://postmarkapp.com/inbound

(both scale well and mandrill gives you 12k emails for free each month. postmark on the other hand offers a bunch of credits for free to start)

The way they work is that you set your MX records to their IP and they will recive the message, parse it, and send a POST request to your server with the data as json)